# CSS Hover stops working after button has been clicked on once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a styling issue I can't solve. I've got a simple toggle with two options -- the user can either click on `Toggle1` or `Toggle2`, and the page will update dynamically with different data depending on which toggle is active:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toggle1">Toggle 1</div>
  <div id="toggle2">Toggle 2</div>
</body>

</html>
```

When a toggle is selected/active, it should have a blue background. When a toggle is NOT selected, it should have a white background + orange background on hover. On page load, `toggle1` is selected by default.

This all works perfectly on initial page load -- toggle1 is selected and blue, and toggle2 is white with orange hover. When I click on toggle2, it turns blue, and toggle1 goes back to white.

However, after I've clicked between the toggles, **the orange hover effect stops working**. I can't figure out why this would be. Is it because the elements are being registered as "active" after they've been clicked or something? I can't figure it out.

I've tried using both css and jQuery to attach the hover effect:

CSS:

```
#toggle1:hover, #toggle2:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(toggle1).hover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass("blue");
    },
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass("blue");
    }
  );

  $(toggle2).hover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass("blue");
    },
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass("blue");
    }
  );
```

They are both successful in adding the hover effect on page load, but not after a toggle has been clicked. Hover stops working entirely.

As far as the onClick function, that's in Javascript:

JS:

```
const showToggle1 = () => {
    // ...code to show toggle 1 content 

    // change background colors from blue to white
    $(toggle2).css({ background: "#FFFFFF", color: "#000000" });
    $(toggle1).css({ background: "#0074d9", color: "#FFFFFF" });
}

const showToggle2 = () => {
    // code to show toggle 2 content

    // change background colors from blue to white
    $(toggle1).css({ background: "#FFFFFF", color: "#000000" });
    $(toggle2).css({ background: "#0074d9", color: "#FFFFFF" });
}
```

All I can think is that there must be something that happens when the onClick functions run that interferes with the Hover, but I can't figure out what that would be.

Comment: You are mixing stuff and doing stuff with jQuery that should be done with CSS alone. No need for any jQuery-hover functionality, do all this with CSS. Also don't set `css(...)` directly with jQuery, instead toggle a c lass and handle all styling within the class. So my adivce: Refactor 90% of this, your approach is not future proof at all.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mre]?

Comment: @cloned Ok I see your point here yeah! I can do it all in CSS by toggling classes, that will be cleaner. I was just able to find a solution by adding `background: #0074d9!important` to the :hover in css, but that's hacky and not future-proof. Thanks for the help

Comment: Remember that an inline style attribute will normally take precedence over any CSS specified by a class.

Comment: With that approach you are not really helping yourself, you will most likely run into further problems along the line. I would suggest you have a good look at the basics of how CSS works and then continue with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the cause of the output you are having, but all I can do is to suggest another method. Use the following html, css and js:

```js
toggle1 = document.querySelector("#toggle1");
toggle2 = document.querySelector("#toggle2");
const showToggle1 = () => {
    //Show the Toggle1 Content
    toggle1.classList.add('selected');
    toggle2.classList.remove('selected');
}
const showToggle2 = () => {
    //Show the Toggle2 Content
    toggle2.classList.add('selected');
    toggle1.classList.remove('selected');
}
```

```css
.toggle{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.toggle:hover{
    color: orange;
}
.toggle.selected{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.toggle.selected:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle1" class="toggle selected" onclick="showToggle1()">Toggle1</div>
<div id="toggle2" class="toggle" onclick="showToggle2()">Toggle2</div>
```

That's it! That should work.